# Unable to increase /dev/sda6

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I can't figure out how to increase `/dev/sda6`

If I open gparted I have allocated 50GB. My dev/sda6 is

```
/dev/sda6        12G   12G  162M  99% /
```

I have tried to increase it but gparted does not allow me.

I have also tried growpart with below result

`growpart /dev/sda 6`:

```
NOCHANGE: partition 6 is size 25339904. it cannot be grown
```

Is there a way I can increase it? If not, can I use the allocated space elsewhere and make that the primary storage from now on?

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to boot from usb and use gparted to no success. Will try the gparted live disc download and see

Comment: It doesn't matter which gparted you use. But "to no success" gives no information at all.

Comment: Hi @Pilot6 sorry, I will try to include more, when I use the command
growpart: I get the following:
NOCHANGE: partition 6 is size 25339904. it cannot be grown

If I open gparted the size of /dev/sda6 is at it's limit. I can't increase it despite having additional unused space

Comment: If unused space is not near sda6, you can't use it. Please read all answers in the dupe question.